# How to render/map through an array of objects in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created an RSS feed consuming react component. Currently it only displays the title of the first news item. I want to be able to map all of the post titles into the render.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-rss-feed-xtt86 - This is where my code is located. You will have to use firefox with CORS add on for the post items to come through.

```
this.state = { news: [{}, {}] }; <-- This gets populated with the news items

<div className="panel-list">{this.state.news[1].title}</div> <!-- This is how it is being rendered onto the page at the minute.
```

I am new to react so sorry for the nooby question! Can't wait to get better.

Thank you all so much! Going to be pro with React in no time (;

Comment: You've already mentioned `map`. So how would you use that to iterate over the news array? There are loads of articles/documentation on this out there. Like [this, for example](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#rendering-multiple-components).

Comment: let newsItems = this.state.news.map(function(item, i){
      return <li key={i}>Test</li>
    }) -- I can use something like this but still unsure how to render it?!

Comment: Here's a working version with jQuery removed: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-rss-feed-3d4qu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the example below

```js
var news = [{
    title: 'first title',
    date: 'first news date'
  },
  {
    title: 'second title',
    date: 'second news date'
  },
  {
    title: 'third title',
    date: 'third news date'
  }
]
const panelList = document.getElementById('panel-list')

news.map(item => {
  panelList.innerHTML += `<div class="panel"><h2 class="panel-title"> ${item.title}</h2><span>${item.date}</span></div>`
})
```

```html
<div id="panel-list">

</div>
```

Except the fact that in React you use JSX and you can make that map dirrectly in the **render** function.
The above pure javascript code would translate into :

```
 <div className="panel-list" >
    {this.state.news.map(item => (
      <div className="panel" key={item.title}>
        <h2 className="panel-title">{item.title}</h2>
        <span>{item.date}</span>
      </div>
    ))}
</div>
```

Also, like it has been mentioned in another comment, don't forget to add `key` attribute to each element inside the map ( each `panel` ) so React can identify the items correctly.

Comment: Glad i could help. Cheers !:D. P.S. You will love React :))

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [`map`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#rendering-multiple-components) to render multiple components from an array:

```js
this.state = { news: [{}, {}] };
...

const news = this.state.news.map((newsItem) =>
  <div key={newsItem.id} className="panel-list">{newsItem.title}</div>
);
```

Note that I added a `key` attribute to each div. This is important to give the elements a stable identity as explained [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html). It needs to be an unique identifier for each `news` item ("id" is used here as an example).

To render the `news` variable, you just need to use curly braces. For example, to render it in a div:

```js
<div>{news}</div>
```

You could also render the list directly, without creating a variable (which is a bit messy, though):

```js
<div>
  {this.state.news.map((newsItem) =>
    <div key={newsItem.id} className="panel-list">{newsItem.title}</div>
  )}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Would this map function go in the componentDidMount or the constructor? How would then I then render it in the render function?

Comment: @BennKingy You can define it in the `render` function, and you can either just return the variable in the render function if nothing else will be rendered in this component, or you can use along with other components/JSX elements. For example, in another div: `<div>{news}</div>`

Comment: @BennKingy You could also just render it directly without creating a variable: `{this.state.news.map((newsItem) =>
  <div key={newsItem.id} className="panel-list">{newsItem.title}</div>
)}`